# Mason perl JSON module refuse to work

Tags: json, perl, perl-module, mason

I'm using Mason in one of my projects and I have a problem using the module JSON.

The page `search.mhtml` is working properly with other external modules (`use DBI`) but whenever I use the following code, the browser is giving me an error "No data received":

[image: no data received]

here is my code:

```
<%once>

use strict;
use JSON;

</%once>

bla
```

The script is just printing "bla" after the "<once>" tag ... and that's it ..
When I remove the "use JSON" it's working ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !

After debugging the JSON module I noticed it get stuck when trying to load the module JSON::XS.

I installed it and now everything works...
FYI.